# What happened in surface?

Tags: rendering, materials

I download 3d model of fdx data.
But surface is not good only front side
What happened in surface when like this looks of material?
How should I fix ?
[image]

Comment: Try Properties panel > Data > Geometry Data, click Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Comment: Thank you for checking.
but not fixed.

Comment: Thank you for checking.but not fixed.I will attach the file. please check it[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6822" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6822/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normals are messed up, flip them: *Mesh* > *Normals* > *Recalculate Outside*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. surface is fixed.